# Primefaces Dashboard with 2 panels

Tags: primefaces

I am using prime faces dashboard.I have 2 panels to display. One with "Actions" and other with "My Tasks" . The problem I am facing is two panels are not stretching as per the window size(panel width). If I give width:100% is also not working.
But if I give width and height in pixels its working. 
Is there anywayI can give the width and height in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by adding one more main panel. Primefaces dashboard accepts only Panels as first level components. Later we can place any components inside these panels.

Comment: Great it works now. But showing code, in question and answer is always very much appreciated (required in Q) so others can explicitly see/understand things